# Laravel Test Cases affecting the database - Using best practices

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.7

I have the following controller on my `Laravel` application:

```
class ProjectController extends Controller {
    ...
    public function index() {
        $projects = Project::where('is_completed', false)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->withCount(['tasks' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('is_completed', false);
            }])->get();
        return response()->json($projects);
    }
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
        ]);
        $project = Project::create([
            'name' => $validatedData['name'],
            'description' => $validatedData['description'],
        ]);
        return response()->json('Project created!');
    }
    ...
}
```

which is referenced by the following route:

```
Route::get('projects', 'ProjectController@index');
Route::post('projects', 'ProjectController@store');
```

Also, I have the following test file:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class ProjectTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testCreateProjects()
    {
        $response = $this->post(
            '/api/projects',
            [
                'name' => 'Project 01 Title',
                'description' => 'Project 01 Description',
            ]
        );
        $response = $this->post(
            '/api/projects',
            [
                'name' => 'Project 02 Title',
                'description' => 'Project 02 Description',
            ]
        );

        $response = $this->get('/api/projects');
        $data = $response->json();

        $this->assertSame(2, count($data));
    }
}
```

As the live database I use: `MySQL`. This is a must.

On the file: `/.env.testing` I specified a test `MySQL` database so I don't make changes on the live database.

There are few files like the following:

```
/database/migrations/<TIMESTAMP>_create_projects_table.php
```

that create the the required tables when running the some of the following commands:

```
$ php artisan:migrate
$ php artisan:migrate --env=testing
```

I run the test cases with the command:

```
$ phpunit
```

The test case above works well only if the test database is empty.

Then I want to know what are the best practices here to run the test cases?, for example, maybe:

- clean each table before running the test cases?
- use another kind of database, maybe an `on-the-fly` database, `SQLite`, etc. (but having in mind that the live database needs to be `MySQL`).

Any idea about this? I'm looking for the best practices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQLite in memory. Another good option is to use database transactions where you can rollback the queries after each test. Laravel provides a convenient `DatabaseTransactions` trait for testing.